# GIT fatal: loose object

Tags: php, git, laravel, nginx

Friends need help.

After a system failure on the host there was such a mistake.

```
Fatal error: unknown class App\Entry in /home/uzbek/uzbek.rf/www/app/Vacancy.php on line 25
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown comperssion method)
fatal: loose object 130dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba (stored in    .git/objects/13/0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba) is corrupt 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The site gives you a white screen , what to do?

I understand that this is a problem with Git, but I'm with him, unfortunately , bad. :(

Comment: @codeWizard
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you have a "good" copy of the repository

First of all you need to know if you have a backup somewhere (another copy of the repository).

If you do simply grab the last good copy and you are good to go.

#### If you don not have a "good" copy of the repository

If will be hard to "fix" the repository.
First of all try to find out which file is broken:

```
git show 0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba
or:
git cat-file -p 0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba
```

Once you know which file is it try to recover it from the history of your editor.

You can also run :

```
git fsck --full
```

to see if you have some other "broken" objects.

Comment: After I introduced git show 0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba
There was the following :
fatal: ambiguous argument '0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: try to run the git fsck and see the results. It should display all the "problematic" items

Comment: After the command : 
`code`git fsck --full`code` 
`code`error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack 130dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba header
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 130dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba (stored in .git/objects/13/0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba) is corrupt`code`

Comment: How do I resolve these errors ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It means that the file is corrupted and some bytes are not written to disk correctly (check-sum is not ok). you should get the object from another good copy of the repository (from someone who has this object).

Comment: I have a copy on bitbucket, but I do not know what commands must be entered to replace this file ? I'm afraid that just spoil everything :(

Comment: Make a copy of this repository. Then clone the repository form bitbucket, run the `git cat-file -p <sha1>` and see which file is it then fix it by pasting the code and adding the file back to the repository,

Comment: I understand you correctly , I need to make a copy bitbucket project , and then on the command line to register the following code :
`code` git cat-file -p 0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba

Comment: make a copy of the corrupted repository. then clone again the good on from bitbucket and copy the `git cat-file -p 0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba`